# Code to convert PostGIS Hex to string

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have PostGis database build on PostSql. 
Is there python or any language code to decode postgis hex?

For example,
0102000020E6100000020000007925A437FFFA53C04100AC0C45A14540035E8F61FFFA53C0747BD20945A14540

This is the data I have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function [st_astext](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) directly in PostgreSql.

Using your example, it gives:

```
select ST_AsText('0102000020E6100000020000007925A437FFFA53C04100AC0C45A14540035E8F61FFFA53C0747BD20945A14540');
-- > LINESTRING(-79.9218272307388 43.2599197234963,-79.9218372249671 43.2599193837877)
```

Comment: I am new to PostGIS and SQL. A lot of thing need to learn.. May I ask another simple question?  I tried this sql query: Select ST_AsText(Select line from pathway1f). I want to use ST_AsText() for a query result. But, I got error. Is there someway else to do this? Thank you!

Comment: @chen of course! ... as another question (not in comments)

Comment: okey, but I need to wait for 90 minutes to post a new question :(